# Avoiding Arrow Pattern with C# Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core, pattern-matching

I have started to use C# 7's type based [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). A method that only manages a single pattern-based result looks very clean and is easy to reason about.

However, once a second pattern-based result that depends on the first pattern-based result creates an arrow anti-pattern, and will only get worse with n-results that depend on each other.

Here is an simplified example that demonstrates the arrow pattern:

```cs
public Result<bool> ValidateSomething(string strId)
{
    var id = Guid.Parse(strId);
    Result<Something> fetchSomethingResult = new SomethingDao.FetchSomething(id);
    switch (fetchSomethingResult)
    {
        case ValueResult<Something> successfulSomethingResult:
            Result<Related> fetchRelatedFieldsResult = new RelatedDao.FetchRelatedFields(successfulSomethingResult.Value.RelatedId);

            switch (fetchRelatedFieldsResult)
            {
                case ValueResult<Related> successfulFieldValueResult:
                    var isValid = successfulSomethingResult.Value.ComparableVal <= successfulFieldValueResult.Value.RelatedComparableVal;
                    return new ValueResult<bool>(isValid);
                case ValueNotFoundResult<Related> _:
                    return new ValueNotFoundResult<bool>();
                case ErrorResult<Related> errorResult:
                    return new ErrorResult<bool>(errorResult.ResultException);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected Result Type Received.");
            }
        case ValueNotFoundResult<Something> notFoundResult:
            return new ValueNotFoundResult<bool>();
        case ErrorResult<Something> errorResult:
            return new ErrorResult<bool>(errorResult.ResultException);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected Result Type Received.");
    }
}
```

For reference, these are the definitions for the `Result` classes:

```cs
public abstract class Result<T>
{

}

public class ValueResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public ValueResult()
    {
    }

    public ValueResult(T inValue)
    {
        Value = inValue;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class ValueNotFoundResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public ValueNotFoundResult()
    {
    }
}

public class ErrorResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public Exception ResultException { get; set; }

    public ErrorResult()
    {
    }

    public ErrorResult(Exception resultException)
    {
        ResultException = resultException;
    }
}
```

What options are there to handle this type of code better? What suggestions do you have for the previous examples? How do I avoid the arrow anti-pattern with pattern-based results?

Comment: You can move nested ones in separate methods (they can be local ones).

Comment: I think it's better to ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could extract out the switch logic into a method that handles the error, not found, and default cases the same way and allows you to pass in a `Func<T, Result<bool>>` to handle the success case.

Comment: Thank you @PavelAnikhouski. I have made a duplicate question there. (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243934/avoiding-arrow-pattern-with-c-pattern-matching)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski [the code above appears to be too hypothetical](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for Code review. Please familiarize yourself with what is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR before recommending users post there

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only really doing anything with the result in case it was successfull, it seem fairly simple to move the switch to an extension method. You might need two extensions, depending on if the function return a new result or just T, something like :

```
    public static Result<TOut> SelectValue<TIn, TOut>(this Result<TIn> self, Func<TIn, Result<TOut>> select)
    {
        switch (self)
        {
            case ErrorResult<TIn> errorResult: return new ErrorResult<TOut>(errorResult.ResultException);
            case ValueNotFoundResult<TIn> valueNotFoundResult: return new ValueNotFoundResult<TOut>();
            case ValueResult<TIn> valueResult: return select(valueResult.Value);
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(self));
        }
    }

    public static Result<TOut> SelectValue<TIn, TOut>(this Result<TIn> self, Func<TIn, TOut> select)
    {
        switch (self)
        {
            case ErrorResult<TIn> errorResult: return new ErrorResult<TOut>(errorResult.ResultException);
            case ValueNotFoundResult<TIn> valueNotFoundResult: return new ValueNotFoundResult<TOut>();
            case ValueResult<TIn> valueResult: return new ValueResult<TOut>(select(valueResult.Value));
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(self));
        }
    }
```

You can then handle the success-cases like this:

```
        var result = fetchSomethingResult
            .SelectValue(something => new RelatedDao.FetchRelatedFields(something.RelatedId))
            .SelectValue(related => related.CompareVal >= 5);
```

If you need to use values from both "Something" and "Related" you will unfortunately need to nest calls.

```
        var result = fetchSomethingResult
            .SelectValue(something => new RelatedDao.FetchRelatedFields(something.RelatedId).SelectValue(related => related.CompareVal >= 5));
```